# Truncated cone - calculating top/bottom area without either radius

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to figured out if it's possible to isolate/calculate the top and surface area (and thereby the radius of either circles) by only having the volume ($ V = 1820 \ \textrm m ^ 3 $), vertical height ($ h = 1 \ \textrm m $) and slope ($ 1 : 5 $).

Is this possible, or am i missing essential data? I've been trying to combine formulas, but I feel like I'm missing some parts.

$$ V = \frac 1 3 \cdot \pi \cdot h \cdot \left( r _ 1 ^ 2 + r _ 2 ^ 2 + r _ 1 \cdot r _ 2 \right) $$
$$ r _ 1 =  r _ 2 - \sqrt { a ^ 2 - h ^ 2 } $$
$$ r _ 2 =  r _ 1 + \sqrt { a ^ 2 - h ^ 2 } $$

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have $ V = \frac{1}{3} \pi h (r_1^2 + r_2^2 + r_1 r_2 ) $ as well as $ \dfrac{r_2 - r_1} { h } = \dfrac{1}{5}$

These are two equations in the two unknowns $r_1$ and $r_2$.  By substitution from the second equation into the first, you get a quadratic equation with one variable only, and can be solved using the quadratic formula.  Then find the other radius, using the second equation.